# Can't find the solution to this error in Apache NetBeans 13

Tags: java, xml, maven, netbeans, xhtml

I was creating a project on NetBeans with Java, XHTML, and XML.
Everything was going fine until I re-installed my IDE because of some problems.
While re-running the project I came across this error which I am unable to solve.
Here is the error

```
Failed to execute goal on project xxxx: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.xxxxxx:xxx:war:1.0: Failed to collect dependencies at net.sf.jasperreports:jasperreports:jar:6.11.0 -> com.lowagie:itext:jar:2.1.7.js7: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.lowagie:itext:jar:2.1.7.js7: Could not transfer artifact com.lowagie:itext:pom:2.1.7.js7 from/to maven-default-http-blocker (http://0.0.0.0/): Blocked mirror for repositories: [jaspersoft-third-party (http://jaspersoft.jfrog.io/jaspersoft/third-party-ce-artifacts/, default, releases+snapshots), jr-ce-releases (http://jaspersoft.jfrog.io/jaspersoft/jr-ce-releases, default, releases+snapshots)] -> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

Please give me your suggestions and solutions. And please tell me whether I should change any preferences or not.
Thanking You

Comment: The problem is: `(http://0.0.0.0/): Blocked mirror for repositories: ` See for details: https://maven.apache.org/docs/3.8.1/release-notes.html

Comment: no it is not working